# How can I call event scrollView scrolls up or down in React Native?

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I have a scrollView element and I want to call different callback functions if user scrolls down or up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [onScroll](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#onscroll) prop to get notified whenever the user scrolls.

In order to achieve your desired effect, you just need to store the position and if an update comes, check if the y position change with by a positive amount of pixel (down) or with a negative amount of pixels (up).

As a functional React component this can look like this:

```jsx
function MyComponent() {
  // we use a ref here in order to store the value between rendering without triggering an update (like useState would)
  const scrollYRef = useRef(0)
  return (
    <ScrollView 
      onScroll={(event) => {
          // 0 means the top of the screen, 100 would be scrolled 100px down
          const currentYPosition = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y
          const oldPosition = scrollYRef.current

          if(oldPosition < currentYPosition) {
              // we scrolled down
          } else {
              // we scrolled up
          }
          // save the current position for the next onScroll event
          scrollYRef.current = currentYPosition
      }}
      ....
    />
  )
}
```